# Help with this function proof

Tags: functions, proof-writing

> *If a function is bijective then its inverse is unique.*

I came across this in my textbook and was wondering how it is proved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In any context where you have an associative binary operation with an identity $e$, inverses are unique.

Indeed, if $ab=e$ and $ca=e$, then
$$
c=ce=c(ab)=(ca)b=eb=b.
$$
*(more properly,  this shows that if a right-inverse and a left-inverse exist, they are equal and are thus the inverse)*

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a given bijection, and let $g_1,g_2 : Y \to X$ be inverses. That is, functions whose compositions with $f$ are the identity maps. Try to show that $g_1(y) = g_2(y)$ for all $y \in Y$ (by somehow getting an $f$ into play); then $g_1 = g_2$, and you have shown that the inverse is unique.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to recall that a function $f:A\to B$ is just a set of ordered pairs $f\subset A\times B$. If the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists (and it will if $f$ is bijective), then $(x,y)\in f^{-1} \iff (y,x)\in f.$ The co-ordinates are simply reversed. Clearly, there is only one such set of reversed co-ordinates and $f^{-1}$ would be unique.